# How do I clear Bootstrap remote modal content on close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am launching a modal with remote content (on the same domain, however). The modal can be opened several times with different content on the same page, so when it closes, I need it to `clear` the `.modal-body` part.

I tried to do it like this:

```
function close_modal()

{

    $('.modal').modal('hide');

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });


}
```

But for some reason the previous content is still visible for a split second when I open another modal target. I also checked the source code and the content loaded previously is still there. How do I fix this? Here is my markup:

```
$('a[rel=modal]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var modal = $('#modal').modal();
    modal
        .find('.modal-body')
        .load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus) {
            if ( textStatus === 'success' || 
                 textStatus === 'notmodified') 
            {
                modal.show();
            }
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" 
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="plan-info" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-screen">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- /# content goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mister @user1996496 Can you provide a JsFiddle, please?

Comment: Is the previous content still visible for a split second if you open it a third time?

Comment: Yes he is. Look up jQuery's load function.

Comment: @joshhunt yes it happens every time

Comment: @JeancarloFontalvo i tried but jsfiddle doesn't allow remote content to be loaded apparently..

Comment: Have a look at my answer and see if it helps. But if it is happening every time it probably isn't a full solution.

Comment: Oh, I just realized it ^-^.  Why don't you try `empty` or `html("")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's `empty` method to remove all child nodes from `.modal-body`:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').empty();
});
```

Comment: I don't think this would help, it is essentially the same as `$(this).removeData('bs.modal');` right?

Comment: @joshhunt I don't believe that to true - `removeData` and `empty` are very different methods. `removeData` only removes `data-` attributes where `empty` removes child nodes.

Comment: I could well be wrong but I assume that is where the Bootstrap js takes over. This article seems to think so but I can't find any info about it in the docs: https://coderwall.com/p/yo1i4q/clear-bootstrap-modal-content-after-close

Comment: Wouldn't that only apply to using the `remote` attribute, not when you are manually calling `.load(...)` and setting the content yourself?

Comment: Right on @user1996496, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that you aren't listening for the close until after you have already closed it. You have:

```
// Hide the modal
$('.modal').modal('hide');

// Start listening for the hide event, if the modal closes remove the data
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Instead move either move the hide listener so it runs before the hide event (probably outside the function because it only needs to start listening once) or remove it and simply have `$('.modal').removeData('bs.modal');`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your modals aren't doing anything special, you might find it easier to use something like [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/), which generates your Bootstrap modal on the fly. Your code would look something like:

```
$('a[rel=modal]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(url)
        .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {
            // store a reference to the bootbox object
            var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
                message: response
            });
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error){
            /* Do something when the form can't be loaded */
        });
});
```